# Missing sonar.properties file post starting up the Sonar applicaiton

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed SonarQube 5.1 with MySQL DB. 
The issue I am facing is after I start my application, "sonar.properties" which was supposed to be under "/conf/" directory is not seen at all. What I see is "wrapper.conf" file and nothing else.I need to configure LDAP/AD and I need to modify the sonar.properties file for this. I am struck here as I am unable to locate the sonar.properties. Please suggest where to look for it?

Do I need sonar runner?

Answer (score 0):

I have never see the sonar.properties file disappear by itself so the most probable is that someone did something. 
Anyway, the original sonar.properties that you have probably modified previously in order to run SonarQube with the connexion to your DB, is still in the SonarQube file you have downloaded, so you can reinstall it.

There are different ways to run an analysis, with the Sonar Runner or not: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code